# $KG$-module of finite $K$-dimension contains a simple $KG$-submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, group-rings

Let $K$ be a field, $G$ a group and $KG$ the corresponding group ring.
Let $M$ be a $KG$-module, therefore it can also be viewed as a $K$-vector space.
Suppose that $M$ has finite $K$-dimension, $\dim_KM = n$.
Then, $\exists U \leq M$ a $KG$-submodule of $M$ such that $U$ is simple.

Is this result true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply say that because $M$ is finite dimensional, it is also apparently Artinian, and so the collection of all nonzero submodules must contain a minimal element.

Answer (score -1):

I arrived at the following proof, just wanted to make sure it is fine.

Proof.

If $M$ is not simple it means that $\exists T_1 < M$ a non-zero proper submodule of $M$.
Since $T$ is a $KG$-submodule of $M$ it is also a $K$-subspace of $M$ viewed as a $K$-vector space.
We have that $\dim_k T_1 = n_1 \leq n$.
If $n_1 = n$ it would mean that $T_1 = M$ when viewing them as vector spaces.
Thus, $n_1 < n$.

If $T_1$ is not simple we may apply the same argument inductively in at most $n$ steps, until arriving at a $T_m$ such that $T_m$ is simple or has $\dim_KT_m = 1$.
In case that $\dim_kT_m =1$, suppose that $T \leq T_m$ is a submodule, then it is also a $K$-subspace of $T_m$.
However, since $T_m$ is of dimension $1$, its only subspaces are $0$ and itself, thus $T_m$ is simple.

We have found $T_m$ as a simple submodule of $M$.